# are we actually doing unsorted joins on hadoop data?

Tags: apache-pig, apache-spark

1. Raw join on two data sets of size `N` and `M` is `O(N*M)`.
2. Sort of both datasets is `O(N*log(N)+M*log(M))`
3. Join on sorted data set is is `O(N+M)`

*ERGO*: doing the join on unsorted data (assuming that the sizes of the data sets are not exponentially unbalanced: `M>>log(N)` and `N>>log(M)`) is a sacrilege against [TAOCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming).

At the same time, neither [pig](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#join-inner) nor [spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SchemaRDD.html#join(org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD,%20org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.JoinType,%20scala.Option)) seem to think about it.
They don't even mention the simple idea of partitioning the data by the key, which would reduce the inter-node communication to 0.

**What am I missing here? Why is this issue being ignored?**

Joins do take noticeable time, so speeding them up is not such a crazy idea.
(the same goes for `group by`, btw).

PS. I understand that the joins are *not* done the stupid way, but go though the sort. However, this sort is done *every time* I do a join; I cannot sort the set once and then have all future joins benefit from it. Note that sort is *more expensive* than the sorted join! And note that the traditional relational DBs have had the notion of indexes just for this purpose for a long time!

Comment: Are you talking about map side joins? If so then I believe you are responsible to provide already sorted data, for example as a result of large distributed sort done by previous map/reduce job. At least that's how it works in Java Hadoop Apis.

Answer (score 0):

The high level flow of a MapReduce job is Map -> Shuffle -> Sort -> Reduce.

MapReduce joins are typically done in the reduce phase, by which point the data has already been sorted.

Comment: I know, see the PS. What I am upset about is that I cannot pre-sort the data.